# Microsoft Graph API: Get message with expand and filter fails with an exception: "Found an unbalanced bracket expression." (using C#)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have an issue when getting a message and a predefined property by its property tag from CONTOSO using Microsoft Graph. I want to get the "ItemClass" property with the property tag "0x001a" as extended property.

1. When using the graph explorer the following GET request works fine:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADllMzJhZmVmLWE4MzgtNDViZS04NmM5LTBjMDhiMTBlNzMwYwBGAAAAAABJSnHDPwmbTJ60RQw_Q9SDBwCyg33-YW4bRI0rrBOy6gXhAAAAAAEMAACyg33-YW4bRI0rrBOy6gXhAAAXMQ5nAAA=?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq 'String 0x001a')`

2. If I make the same request from c# I get the following exception, even if I use URL encoding (see B in code below):

Message: Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Found an unbalanced bracket expression.

The c# code looks as follows:

```
    ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = 
        new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
    
    GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = 
        new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

    var message = await this.GraphServiceClient
        .Me
        .Messages["AAMkADllMzJhZmVmLWE4MzgtNDViZS04NmM5LTBjMDhiMTBlNzMwYwBGAAAAAABJSnHDPwmbTJ60RQw_Q9SDBwCyg33-YW4bRI0rrBOy6gXhAAAAAAEMAACyg33-YW4bRI0rrBOy6gXhAAAXMQ5nAAA="]
        .Request() 
        .Expand("singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x001A'") // A
        //.Expand("singleValueExtendedProperties(%24filter%3D(id%20eq%20%27String%200x001A%27)") // B) 
        .GetAsync();
```

What is wrong with the filter expression?

Comment: Can you use Fiddler (or similar) to trace the raw request that c# is sending and compare it to what you are putting into graph explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `)` inside the `.Expand()`. Change it to

```
.Expand("singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x001A')")
```